# Where is l3meta.pdf?

Tags: latex3

LaTeX News, Issue 35 (June 2022) references the file `l3meta.pdf`.

In TeXLive 2022 (updated to current versions of everything) under macOS, where is `l3meta.pdf` to be found?

Neither `texdoc l3meta` nor a file search reveals the file.

Comment: sorry it was a typo (there is also a l3pdfmeta in the pdfmanagement bundle and it got mixed together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's corrected to `ltmeta` (part of `source2e.pdf`). See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/94f427847360370ab77e40804ba64febc5609494.

```
diff --git a/base/doc/ltnews35.tex b/base/doc/ltnews35.tex
index 0e0cda79b..a035e4d5c 100644
--- a/base/doc/ltnews35.tex
+++ b/base/doc/ltnews35.tex
@@ -208,7 +208,7 @@ \section{Document metadata interface}
 is carried out and is in a wider alpha or beta test phase.
 
 Documentation about the new command and
-already existing keys are in \file{l3meta.pdf} and \file{documentmetadata-support.pdf}
+already existing keys are in \file{ltmeta} (part of \file{source2e.pdf})  and \file{documentmetadata-support.pdf}
 and also in the documentation of the \pkg{pdfmanagement-testphase} package.
 
 Package and class authors can test if a user has used \cs{DocumentMetadata}
```

Comment: If I use `texdoc ltmeta`, I get either an article "Un ejemplo de c ́omo escribir un art ́ıculo que se publicar ́a en La Gaceta de la RSME" or, if I do it a 2nd time, "Typesetting multilingual documents with ANTOMEGA".!

Comment: The corrected description means `ltmeta` doesn't have its own documentation, only the source code with comments found in `texdoc source2e`, currently sec. "File o `ltmeta.dtx`".

Comment: sorry for the typo, you need `texdoc source2e` at the moment ... cleanp of the documentation is planned for the next release, right now it is is a bit scattered unfortunately.